# How to change in a dataframe columns to rows based on same name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

As you can see I have a dataframe with several columns with the same name but split into 0., 1. until 27.

How can I take all the values of 1.name and have it under 0.name?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that for all 0<=n<=27 the column names' suffixes are the same, one solution can be:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re


# pattern to extract colum name suffix
pattern = re.compile('^\d\.([\w\.]+)')

# getting all the distinct column names/fields
fields = set([pattern.match(colname).group(1) for colname in df.columns])

# max prefix number, for you 27
n = 27
partitions = []
for i in range(0,n+1):
    # creating column selector for partitions
    columns_for_partition = list(map(lambda field: str(i) + f'.{field}', fields))
    
    # get partition from dataframe and renaming column to field name (removing n. prefix) 
    partition = df[columns_for_partition].rename(lambda x: x.split('.',1)[1], axis=1)
    partitions.append(partition)
new_df = pd.concat(partitions)
print(new_df)
```

With an initial dataframe `df`

```py
  0.name  0.something 1.name  1.something
0      a            1      d            4
1      b            2      e            5
2      c            3      f            6
```

The resulting dataframe `new_df` will look like:

```py
  name  something
0    a          1
1    b          2
2    c          3
0    d          4
1    e          5
2    f          6
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Did your column naming pattern changed?  Maybe try to use this regex pattern instead `pattern = re.compile('^[\d\.]*([\w\.]+)')`. This will also match, even if column names are not prefixed with <decimal>.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! It worked. This helped me a lot! :)